# Getting the content of the Intent's Extra in new Activity

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

I send data from one `Activity` (actually a `Fragment` in my case) to a new `Activity` using an `Intent`. Here's the code I use:

```
Intent detailIntent = new Intent(getActivity(), NewActivity.class);
detailIntent.putExtra("News", n);
startActivity(detailIntent);
```

I know how to get the data in my `NewActivity` using

```
News news = (News) getIntent().getSerializableExtra("News");
```

and then populate the different UI components that I created in the XML.

but where should those lines of code be. There are multiple methods that it could possibly live in:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
public View onCreateView(String name, Context context, AttributeSet attrs)
public View onCreateView(View parent, String name, Context context, AttributeSet attrs)
```

Comment: what do you need `LayoutInflater.Factory[2]#onCreateView` for?

Comment: That's my question, I'm not sure where to put that code. In my Fragments I initialize global my global vars in OnCreateView(LayoutInflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)

Comment: in `Activity` use `onCreate`

Answer (score 3):

Since it is information that you receive from the previous Activity and it is not going to be modified, you should read it from the onCreate method.

Answer (score 0):

If you navigate back and forth between your Activities and the extra can change it is best to put the line

```
News news = (News) getIntent().getSerializableExtra("News");
```

in `onResume`, as `onCreate` will only be called on the first creation of the Activity, but not if it is on the stack and moved to the top later. If your second Activity is static and the extra never changes it is better to have the code in `onCreate`.

Comment: why do you want to read that extra again and again in `onResume`? will it change from time to time? no, so read it once in `onCreate`

Comment: Hence why I wrote put it in either onCreate or onResume depending on your needs.

Comment: The contents of the variable 'n' can change

Comment: the serialized contents? how come?

Comment: The Data is coming from a ListView, so if I hit back and click on another item it would be different. At that point, would the NewActivity be recreated or resumed?

Comment: Depends on if you finished the NewActivity or left it on the stack. If you hit back you probably finished it and onCreate will be called again.

Comment: @LaurentRivard if you hit back and open another item it will call again onCreate. So that is the method that you must use to read intent extras.